# How to combine these two grep statements

Tags: files, grep, regular-expression, search

I need to select the lines that are not empty lines and do not start with `//`. I can perform two separate grep commands as follows:

To extract the lines that are not empty line:

```
grep -v -E '^$' test.txt
```

To extract the lines that do not start with `//`:

```
grep -v '//' test.txt
```

How can I combine both commands in one?

Comment: You could also solve this with sed: `sed -E '\#^($|//)#d' test.txt`

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
 grep -ve '^$' -e '^//' file
```

From man:

> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>
> ```
> Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple search patterns,
> ```

or using extended regular expression (-E ):

```
 grep -v -E '^($|//)' file
```

from man:

> Two regular expressions may be joined by the infix operator |; the resulting regular expression matches any string matching either alternate expression.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is already combined (with errors explained later on):

```
grep -v -E '^$' | grep -v '//' test.txt
```

Only the first part from the left (until the `|`) excludes empty lines. The first error is that the rightmost statement is provided with `test.txt`, which should already be fed to the leftmost statement, so that both commands operate on this input. I mean this:

```
grep -v -E '^$' test.txt | grep -v '//'
```

The second error is that the `'//'` definition should in fact be `'^//'`, where `^` indicates the beginning of line. All together:

```
grep -v -E '^$' test.txt | grep -v '^//'
```

Such chaining of `grep` uses is a common practice. See the other answers for how to merge them into one `grep` process.

Answer (score 0):

So you want lines that start with characters other than `//`:

```
grep -E '^([^/]|.[^/])' file
```